# "System" in chrome javascript profiling

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome-devtools

When profiling a tool I've been building (a canvas-based graphing library), I've noticed that a majority of the time is spent in a task labeled "System" in the summary (see screenshot). I naturally want to optimize the thing that's taking the most compute, yet I can find nothing about what this task actually is. **What is the system task and what causes it?**

[image: Summary tab in developer tools]

Other details / things I've tried:

- I can find nothing about it in [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference).
- Can reproduce consistently, even after rebooting my computer
- My first thought was that it was garbage collection, but that's explicitly listed in the call tree. I also rewrote my code to be more memory efficient (allocating an order of magnitude fewer objects), and the system task usage did not change.
- I tried clicking on the grey bar in the timeline that represents the system task, hoping it would reveal more details. No dice.
- In Firefox, there's no system task, and more idle time, though a surprisingly high amount of time is spent updating the DOM.
- In Safari, 15% of the time is spent in javascript and essentially all of the remaining time is spent in a Paint, with no idle time.
- In Brave, we get the exact same symptoms as Chrome (relatively low time in scripting, lots of time in "System").
- In Chromium (rather than Chrome), symptoms are identical as expected.

I have a couple theories:

- Maybe my code is hitting an edge case of the JIT that causes it to run too frequently.
- Maybe I'm doing something dumb with the canvas.
- Maybe I'll be able to fix my problem by trial and error, but while that'd be welcome it's ultimately tangential.

I want to understand what exactly the system task is and what causes it to run.

Comment: Could it be the system calls you're doing for canvas manipulation, i.e. all the native methods, or are those accounted for in "scripting"?

Comment: Good thinking! I thought they were, but I tried commenting those out and the system task usage went way down without changing the time of the function that calls it. The lack of documentation is odd, and the performance is odder (I'm just drawing line segments). I'll do some more investigation + try doing the canvas manipulation in rust/wasm and report my findings.

Comment: There's a [lot of stuff](/a/40173057) under that category, actually, so it's better to use `chrome://tracing` (look for [tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=using+chrome+tracing)) to see what happens inside the system time so you can make a guess about the culprit based on that info. P.S. Devtools doesn't show some activities by default so you need to enable them manually, https://puu.sh/FrDS5/8bc05c5844.png (it's somewhat [complicated](https://hackernoon.com/hidden-experimental-features-in-chrome-devtools-2ae93b11b628) in current Chrome but simple in Chrome Canary).